# Electron ipcRenderer seems broken

Tags: electron, chromium

Original issue: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/37067

I'm using Electron 12.0.6 and `ipcRenderer` seems broken sometime (both macOS and Windows):

- The main process never received the message sent by `ipcRenderer.send()`, `ipcRenderer.sendSync()`, `ipcRenderer.invoke()`, `ipcRenderer.postMessage()`
- Other renderer process never received the message sent by `ipcRenderer.sendTo()`
- `ipcRenderer.sendSync()` always returns `null`
- `ipcRenderer.on()` can still receive the message from other process
- Unable to create a new `<webview>` element
- `ipcRenderer` works fine in other webContents, including window and webview
- `ipcRenderer` works normal after the page reloaded

I wonder how could I debug this issue? What information would help to debug this issue and how to collect such information?

Is there any guesses on this issue? For example, what causes `ipcRenderer.sendSync()` always returns `null`?

EDIT: After reading the source code of electron@12.0.6, it seems like chromium mojo message not sent?

```
// shell/renderer/api/electron_api_ipc_renderer.cc

  v8::Local<v8::Value> SendSync(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                gin_helper::ErrorThrower thrower,
                                bool internal,
                                const std::string& channel,
                                v8::Local<v8::Value> arguments) {
    if (!electron_browser_remote_) {
      thrower.ThrowError(kIPCMethodCalledAfterContextReleasedError);
      return v8::Local<v8::Value>();
    }
    blink::CloneableMessage message;
    if (!electron::SerializeV8Value(isolate, arguments, &message)) {
      return v8::Local<v8::Value>();
    }

    blink::CloneableMessage result;
    // >>> This line was called
    electron_browser_remote_->MessageSync(internal, channel, std::move(message),
                                          &result);
    return electron::DeserializeV8Value(isolate, result);
  }

  v8::Global<v8::Context> weak_context_;
  mojo::Remote<electron::mojom::ElectronBrowser> electron_browser_remote_;
```

Comment: I come to the same conclusion as the Electron team in the issue you've linked. Electron 12.0.6 is >1,5 years old at this point, so it would be safer in any way to upgrade your app to use the latest Electron version. If you don't upgrade, you cannot know whether any subsequent version already fixed the issue you're experiencing and thus only invest more and more time into finding a solution someone else possibly already found, Also, as a rule of thumb, you don't want to compile Electron yourself; it will just create more problems and take an absurd amount of time (like any flavour of Chrome).

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner Thank you for your reply. But sadly we don't have the plan to upgrade the Electron version for our App in a short time. So what I can do is try to figure out the cause of this issue and avoid it. Is there any idea on debugging this issue? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, I bet you won't find *and* fix the bug "in a short time" either. Anyhow, I don't know how you would debug such issue since it seems closely related to Chromium source code, which is huge. I wanted to say that the cost-effectiveness ratio of debugging this on your own is insane compared to getting support from the Electron team by upgrading to a new version. You also should consider updating from a security perspective: New Electron versions bring new Chromium versions which include serious security fixes. Also, you're trying to fix multiple (possibly unrelated) problems at once here.

Comment: seeing your source code would help. I have no idea what your code is doing